# Windows script host error 800A0046

Tags: vbscript

I'm receiving the following error when I run my program:

Script: C: My Folder\Tracking Macro.vbs
Line:   70
Char:   1
Error:  Permission denied
Code:   800A0046
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Here is the code.

```
' Set constants for reading, writing, and appending files
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

 ' Sets up the object variables.
 Dim objExcel, objFSO, objTextFile, objCSVFile

' Sets up the string variables.
Dim strTextFile, strHeadLine, strTextLine, strCSVFile

' Sets up the all the string variables for the program.
Dim Desktop, todaysDate, usageDate, myDay, myMonth, myYear

'This creates the required Objects
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Desktop = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\" & "Desktop"

' Set date for date stamp in file name and sheet name
todaysDate = Date()

myMonth = Month(todaysDate)
If Len(myMonth)=1 Then myMonth="0" & myMonth

myDay = Day(todaysDate)
If Len(myDay)=1 Then myDay="0" & myDay

myYear = Right(Year(todaysDate), 2)

usageDate = myMonth & myDay & myYear

' Set up the origin and destination files
strTextFile = (Desktop & "\MacroTracker.txt")
strCSVFile = "C: My Folder\TrackingTesting" & usageDate & ".csv"
strHeadLine = "Macro Name,User ID,Ran At,Contracted Rate,BHVN,Set Number,Provider TIN,Billed Charge,Service Code"

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile)

' Read the entire origin file
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
strTextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Loop

If (objFSO.FileExists(strCSVFile)) Then
' Create object for appending current TXT file to CSV file
Set objCSVFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strCSVFile, ForAppending, True)
' Write an append line of data to the CSV file
objCSVFile.WriteLine strTextLine
Else
' Create CSV file to write to with today's date
Set objCSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strCSVFile, True)
' Create object for appending current TXT file to CSV file
Set objCSVFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strCSVFile, ForAppending, True)
' Write initial header for the CSV file
objCSVFile.WriteLine strHeadLine
' Write an append line of data to the CSV file
objCSVFile.WriteLine strTextLine
End If

' Wait for file to be written to
Wscript.Sleep 600

' Delete origin file to prevent user tampering
objFSO.DeleteFile(strTextFile)
```

Line 70 is the very last line where I'm deleting the text file.  According to every help site I've seen, this is EXACTLY how it should be typed. I checked the permissions of the file...I have full control, so I should be able to delete it.  It's only meant to be a temp file, not something that stores info for long periods of time.

I've checked Microsoft and all other help sites for the error code and have not found any solutions that can help me. I'm hoping someone may have ran into a similar instance and found a resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is still open. You need to add this:

```
objTextFile.Close
```

somewhere before you try to delete it. I would put it right after you're done using the file.

Comment: PERFECT!! I didn't even think of closing it, but it makes sense if I opened it to be able to read it. Thanks for the help. :)